# 'WebFormsBundle' is not a valid script name. The name must end in '.js'

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio

What can i do to solve this error?

[image]

At the first the application was ok but than i dont know what happend. 
i have curectly installed the packages and the references.

and here is the part than as i understand gives the error

```
      <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see 
       http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" 
     Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" 
     Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" 
     Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" 
     Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" 
     Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" 
     Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" 
     Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" 
     Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle"/>
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I'm encountering the same issue now.

Comment: I am facing same problem as well, and not able to find solution for this from anywhere. If you have resolved this problem then please share the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:

Install

Microsoft.AspNet.ScriptManager.WebForms

from Nuget (right-click your solution, select Manage Nuget packages)